# Поиск одной или другой таблицы в BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Таблица на сайте может иметь строку

```
<div class="emptyData">Праздничный день</div>
```

или

```
<a class="strong " title="Технология" 
href="https://">Технология</a>
```

Как можно в bs4 обработать оба значения? Мой код имеет следующий вид:

```
for x in row:
    i = 0
    list = x.find_all('a', {'class':'strong'})
```

Как его дополнить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать как в следующем примере:

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'http://www.garant.ru/company/garant-press/ab/217886/03/'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
found = soup.find_all(['a', 'div'], {'class':['buy-garant', 'controls']})

print(found)
```

Результат:

```
[<a class="buy-garant" href="http://aero.garant.ru/?utm_source=garant&amp;utm_medium=buttom&amp;utm_content=buy-garant&amp;utm_campaign=knop
ka-v-shapke#form_title" title="Купить ГАРАНТ"><span></span>Купить ГАРАНТ</a>, <div class="controls">
<input id="pers_login" name="uname" type="text" value="">
<p class="error-msg" id="error_login">
</p>
</input></div>, <div class="controls">
<input id="pers_password" name="upass" type="password" value="">
<p class="error-msg" id="error_password">
</p>
</input></div>]
```